# compiling SyntaxNet on OS X fails with "error loading package '@jpeg//': Extension file not found"

Tags: macos, tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I can't get SyntaxNet compiled on my MacBook Pro.

I followed the SyntaxNet installation steps here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet#installation

the `bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...` line fails with this output:

`Joachims-MacBook-Pro:syntaxnet joachim$ bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_joachim/2d6c6b79fd5d2f10f2fd8d8e3457de30/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config/BUILD:108:1: error loading package '@jpeg//': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '//third_party:common.bzl': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config:jpeg'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//syntaxnet:test_main' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.823s
ERROR: Couldn't start the build. Unable to run tests.`

Here's some system info:

`Joachims-MacBook-Pro:syntaxnet joachim$ bazel version
Build label: 0.4.3-homebrew
Build target: bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Thu Dec 22 15:20:22 2016 (1482420022)
Build timestamp: 1482420022
Build timestamp as int: 1482420022`

`Joachims-MacBook-Pro:syntaxnet joachim$ python --version
Python 2.7.11`

I pulled the sources as follows:

`Joachims-MacBook-Pro:workspace joachim$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
Cloning into 'models'
...
'aab099711d7e04034cf742ddb9b00dd15edbe99c'`

Comment: possibly related -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6706#issuecomment-273846076

Comment: It's not just you. Having the same trouble, updated past the issue Yaroslav Bulatov linked to.

Comment: Thanks for confirming then. So I guess the solution is to checkout an older version of SyntaxNet? Any hints on which version?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem when compiling on Ubuntu.

Find the file `tensorflow/third_party/jpeg/jpeg.BUILD`

Then, change the code `load("@//third_party:common.bzl", "template_rule")`

to

`load("@org_tensorflow//third_party:common.bzl", "template_rule")`